# How to fully change the background color on a tkinter.ttk Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I have been attempting to make a directory browser for a recent project of mine that I'm developing in python 3.4.4 with tkinter. I do not want the background to be the default color, so I have gone about changing the background of most widgets. I didn't have any trouble until I got to the Treeview. I'm not too good with ttk.Style(), but I still managed to get

```
ttk.Style().configure("Treeview", background="black",
                foreground="white")
```

to work, however this only changes the background of the area included in the widget.
[image: Error]

I checked to see if it was a resizing issue, but everything seems to be in order. I also looked for similar issues online thinking I was doing it wrong and found two links pointing to Bryan Oakley having the same issue back in 2007.

[Bryan Oakley Re: how to get a ttk::treeview with no border](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Tcl/comp.lang.tcl/2007-11/msg00923.html)

[how to create a ttk::treeview without a border?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/o5nmJewZMu0)

Essentially, the conclusion was that this is a bug when run on windows. Because of this, I'm left with 3 general questions:

Am I just entirely missing something obvious and misunderstanding these posts (crossing fingers here) and if so what am I doing wrong? Or if this was really a bug, has there been any solution to it since 2007? And finally if there has not been any solution, does anyone have a way that they've found to work around the issue, no matter how hacky of a solution?

Comment: Have you tried `style.configure("Treeview", fieldbackground="black")`?

Comment: I just tried that now and it seems to have no effect

Comment: I think it is related to the ttk theme you are using, it should work with the theme "clam" (`style.them_use("clam")`).

Comment: That was it j_4321. Thanks a bunch! (I'd love to accept your answer if you'd submit it as a full fledged answer outside the comments. Thank you for your help as well Mr. Yahli

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To make the background of a Treeview totally black, both the `background` and the `fieldbackground` options of the Treeview style need to be set to black.

In addition, not all ttk themes support the `fieldbackground` option, like the "xpnative" and "vista" themes.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style(root)
# set ttk theme to "clam" which support the fieldbackground option
style.theme_use("clam")
style.configure("Treeview", background="black", 
                fieldbackground="black", foreground="white")

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.insert("", 0, "item", text="item")
tree.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Problem with `clam` is it squishes rows tightly together. Problem with `style` in general is it effected all my existing treeview, not just the one I wanted to set color for. Positive side effect: the sparsely populated treeview shrunk the frame to eliminate empty space.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The "clam" style will be applied to all the `ttk` widgets, but  if you don't want all your treeviews to have a black background, you can configure `"black.Treeview"` instead of `"Treeview"` and do `tree.configure(style="black.Treeview")` for the tree you want with a black background.

Comment: Works like a charm. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Use to use this code instead :

```
ttk.Style().configure("Treeview", background="black", 
foreground="white", fieldbackground="black")
```

Hopefully this will help you,

Yahli.

Comment: It does not work with every ttk themes, "vista" and "xpnative" does not seem to support the "fieldbackground" option.