# Can I change the foreground color of a single column in Python Treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

This is the screenshot of my treeview in python tkinter..
I want to change the foreground of "Critical Level" including its children to "Red" or at least red.

```
style = Style()
        style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('open sans', 10), rowheight=20,
                        foreground='#e8e8e8')
        style.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", font=('open sans', 10, 'bold'), foreground='#000000')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by tagging your treeview item instead, and use `tag_configure` to change the displayed colour.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.pack()
c = tree.insert('', 'end', text='This is critical message', tags=('critical',))
tree.insert(c, 'end', text='This is child of critical message', tags=('critical',))
for i in range(5):
    tree.insert('', 'end', text='This is non-critical message')
tree.tag_configure('critical', background='red',foreground="white")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware:
Henry Yik's answer won't work in python 3.7.3 and 3.8.0. However, it works in python 3.6.2.

You can find difference in behaviour using code from answer: 
[How to fully change the background color on a tkinter.ttk Treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816930/how-to-fully-change-the-background-color-on-a-tkinter-ttk-treeview/43834987)